# Theano float64 matrix product value error

Tags: python, numpy, theano

I need to do matrix multiplication with float64 precision matrices.
The following code works in float32 and matrix() instead of dmatrix().
However, when it comes to float64, it fails.

```
import theano
from theano import tensor as T
import numpy

x = numpy.ones((20000, 100), dtype=numpy.float64)
m = T.dmatrix()
mTm = T.dot(m.T, m)
f = theano.function([m], mTm)
f(x)
r = f(x)
r.shape
```

I have the following error:

```
THEANO_FLAGS=device=gpu0 python test.py
Using gpu device 0: GeForce GTX 750 Ti
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
f = theano.function([m], mTm)
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function.py", line 223, in function 
...
ValueError: ('The following error happened while compiling the node', Dot22(Inpl
aceDimShuffle{1,0}.0, <TensorType(float64, matrix)>), '\n', 'invalid token in co
nfig.blas.ldflags', 'asdfadf')
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not related to the GPU, but the value you used for the Theano flag blas.ldflags: 'asdfadf'

This is passed to g++ when compiling again blas. You didn't put value g++ parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [the deep learning tutorial here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/using_gpu.html#tips-for-improving-performance-on-gpu) to see that right now theano calculations only benefit from GPU when `float32` are passed. See also [this thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.mathematics.theano.user/1087) on the mailing list.